# value from ConcurrentHashMap throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, concurrency, nullpointerexception

I'm maintaining multi-threaded legacy code that uses `ConcurrentHashMap`.

There are operations of add and remove in other methods.

In the following code, at some point after collecting few values from the map, it throws `NullPointerException` when executing `synchronize(value)`.

```
public class MyClass{

    private final Map<MyObj, Map<String, List<String>>> conMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    //...

    public void doSomthing((MyObj id){
        List<Map<String, List<String>>> mapsList = new LinkedList<>();
        for(MyObj objId: conMap.keySet()){              
            if(objId.key1.equals(id.key1)){
                mapsList.add(conMap.get(objId));
            }
        }

        for(Map<String, List<String>> map: mapsList){
            synchronized(map){                   // <-- NullPointerException here
                //...
            }
    }

    //...

}
```

I have a feeling that maybe during the iteration in the first loop, records are being remove. And when the line:

```
mapsList.add(conMap.get(objId));
```

being executed, `objId` no longer exist and `mapsList` adding null and as a result, during the second loop `NullPoinerException` is thrown.

Is there any other reason to get this exception?

Comment: I think you are right. But why don't you just debug and prove?

Comment: I can't debug - it happen randomly, multi-threaded, and the input is only available at the client..

Comment: If you can't debug, then you may want to try adding a null check before adding an item to your `mapsList`. If that's working, it proves your assumption is correct. Otherwise, look for any code that could potentially modify the `conMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fallen for the Check-Then-Act anti-pattern. It implies checking a condition (like the presence of a key), followed by acting upon it (like calling `get`), ignoring the possibility that the condition may have changed in-between.

So you encounter a particular key when iterating over `conMap.keySet()`, but by the time you’re invoking `conMap.get(objId)`, the key might not be in the map anymore, which is reported by returning `null`.

It’s strongly recommended to use a key type having a suitable `hashCode`/`equals` implementation, so you don’t need to iterate over the entire map to find matches but can use a single `get(id)`.

However, when you have to iterate over the map and need the values, iterate over the entry set instead of the key set.

```
public void doSomething(MyObj id){
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488
    List<Map<String, List<String>>> mapsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Map.Entry<MyObj, Map<String, List<String>>> e: conMap.entrySet()){              
        if(e.getKey().key1.equals(id.key1)){
            mapsList.add(e.getValue());
        }
    }

    for(Map<String, List<String>> map: mapsList){
        synchronized(map) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```